# how to show all the non – blank lines of a specific file

Tags: 14.04, command-line

how to show all the non – blank lines of a specific file Using Terminal

The command

```
grep -vP '\S' alpha
```

shows *only* blank lines, but I dont know how to show all *non blank* lines in Ubuntu using the terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your command is almost correct. Just remove the `v`.

Then you have `grep -P '\S'`.

The `-v` flag means: "show only lines that *don't* match the pattern"

---

Some alternative commands:

- `grep -v '^$'` Pattern matches "begin of string (^), directly followed by "end of string" ($)
- `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'` same as before, but with optional space in the line (not really empty, but nothing visible)
- `grep  '[^[:space:]]'` greps all lines that contain a non-space character (basically the same you used but does not need the `-P` option)